# Preferred way to represent time of day in JSON/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

Javascript comes with the Date object, providing several utilities for working with *specific* points in time.

However, what if I want to represent a time of day, such as `15:00` which simply denotes a point during any day, rather than being tied to a specific date?

I know I could use a string, but is there a representation which is more standardised for this kind of data?

Answer (score 9):

Depending on how granular you wanted to be, you could use seconds or milliseconds. So:

```
var time = 900; // 900 seconds = 15:00
```

Then in your JavaScript you could instantiate that time in todays date like so:

```
// get the current date and time
var date = new Date();

// reset the hours, mins, seconds, ms
date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

// set according to the stored time
date.setSeconds(time);
```

In answer to a *more standardised* approach: most computers use the [Unix Timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which counts the number of milliseconds from 1 January 1970 UTC. But, as you've already stated, the date is not important to you.

Regardless of the importance of the day/month/year - using seconds or milliseconds is a good way of rehabilitating your data back into the common JavaScript Date object, which is a very useful thing at the application level.

For a mammoth amount of over-consideration and syntactic sugar, you may or may not find [Moment](http://momentjs.com/) useful.

```js
var time = 900;

// get the current date and time
var date = new Date();

// reset the hours, mins, seconds, ms
date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

// set according to the stored time
date.setSeconds(time);

document.body.innerHTML = date;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a standard way of doing what you need but I would do something like the following example. The idea is that we're using a date object for the time parts and ignoring everything else.

```
function time(str) {
  var date = '1970-01-01 {hr:min}:00';
  var _time = new Date(date.replace('{hr:min}', str));

  return {
    getHours: function() {
      return _time.getHours();
    },

    getMinutes: function() {
      return _time.getMinutes();
    },

    getSeconds: function() {
      return _time.getSeconds();
    },

    toString: function() {
      return _time.toLocaleTimeString(); // or use `toTimeString()`
    }
  };
}
```

Usage:

```
var t = time('15:30');
var t2 = time('11:45');

t.getHours(); //=> 15
t.getMinutes(); //=> 30
t.getSeconds(); //=> 0

// We're getting AM and PM for free
t.toString(); //=> "3:30:00 PM"
t2.toString(); //=> "11:45:00 AM"
```

### Update:

The example above doesn't make use of prototypes so every object gets a copy of those methods. If you're going to have a lot of objects, then you might want to use the following version, which uses prototypes. The downside of this version is that it exposes the `this._time` property.

```
var time = (function() {
  var date = '1970-01-01 {hr:min}:00';
  var methods = {
    getHours: function() {
      return this._time.getHours();
    },

    getMinutes: function() {
      return this._time.getMinutes();
    },

    getSeconds: function() {
      return this._time.getSeconds();
    },

    toString: function() {
      return this._time.toLocaleTimeString(); // or use `toTimeString()`
    }
  };

  return function(str) {
    var _instance = Object.create(methods);
    _instance._time = new Date(date.replace('{hr:min}', str));

    return _instance;
  };
}());

var t = time('15:30');
var t2 = time('11:45');
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into this recently as well, since I also wanted to represent time independent of date in JS.

I searched for a standard solution and quickly found there is none. The only thing that came close was to use `Date` and only set time properties on it, as suggested by @shennan. But that felt wrong, since it's exposing methods that have nothing to do with daytime, like `getFullYear()`, which will confuse people if it gets passed around in a program.

Other option was to use some datetime library, but introducing it to just represent a simple time also felt wrong, since those are often heavy in terms of size and their API.

I think the approach @istos went for - exposing only time related methods and using date as the core - is the best. However, it has one little issue that will give you incorrect results if you do calculations with dates and are outside of the UTC+0 timezone, and that is the usage of `getHours()`. This method gives you localized hour count, which skews the result when you subtract eg. `2:00` from `4:00`, so you want to use `getUTCHours()` instead, which returns hour count relative to UTC+0.

So here is a modern, memory efficient solution (by using `class`, every instance refers for methods to one common prototype) which allows for calculations since it both exposes and allows to create itself by using milliseconds (using TypeScript):

```js
class Time {
  private date: Date

  constructor(...args: [number] | [number, number]) {
    if (args.length === 1) {
      this.date = new Date(args[0])
    } else {
      const hours = args[0]
      const minutes = args[1]
      this.date = new Date(Date.UTC(1970, 0, 1, hours, minutes))
    }
  }

  getHours() {
    return this.date.getUTCHours()
  }

  getMinutes() {
    return this.date.getUTCMinutes()
  }

  getTime() {
    return this.date.getTime()
  }

  toString() {
    return `${padWithZero(this.getHours())}:${padWithZero(this.getMinutes())}`
  }
}

const t1 = new Time(4, 30)
const t2 = new Time(1, 15)
const t3 = new Time(t1.getTime() - t2.getTime())
t3.getHours() // 3
t3.getMinutes() // 15
```